# How can I output the content of a RDD in the console

Tags: apache-spark

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkKMeans")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val lines = sc.textFile(args(0))
val data = lines.map(parseVector _).cache()
val K = args(1).toInt
val convergeDist = args(2).toDouble
val kPoints = data.takeSample(withReplacement = false, K, 42).toArray
```

For example,how can I output the content of "lines" or "data"?That's the result I got(kPoints):[Lbreeze.linalg.Vector;@3bfc6a5e

Comment: sorry!I'm new here,and I don't know how to post a question in the site.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the wrong question.

Your question is not how to get the content - you've already did with `RDD.takeSample`. And you also know how to print it to stdout otherwise you won't have such thing like `[Lbreeze.linalg.Vector;@3bfc6a5e`

Things you really need is a readable format. In most case `kPoints.map(_.toString)` should do it. If not, you need to manually write a function to do it. I guess you can try convert `Vector` to `Array[double]` then call `toString`

And: Check on vectors' value is meaningless, why not use some stat method to observe?

Comment: I want to know what the "data" really is,how can I print it to console?

Comment: @hudeqi `kPoints.map(_.toString).foreach(println)`